# the torsion part of grothendieck group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

what is the geometric meaning of the torsion part of grothendieck group of bounded derived category of coherent sheaves and bounded derived category of R-module（R is a ring）？

Comment: The Grothendieck group of what?